# Removing a button if textarea is edited and not saved

Tags: php, jquery, html

I got two forms.

First form contains a button which will mark the task done and retrieve a new task.

Second form is for submitting translated content or work on already saved content.
So it contains a textarea and a save button.
PHP + Mysql will output already saved work in the form if anything exists.

I want to make the Task Done button unavailable in the first form, if the textarea in the second form is edited and the Task done button should appear after the save button have been pressed but I am not sure what the best way is to solve this problem.

I think the best solution will be Jquery but I am no expert.

Comment: try hooking into the `.on('change')` event in jquery for the data you want to watch.. then you should be able to either `remove()` or `hide()` the button

Comment: something like `$('#mytextarea').click(function(){$('#donebtn').hide();});` And `$('#savebtn').click(function(){/*save stuff then */ $('#donebtn').show();});`

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of CSS and Javascript manipulation.

#### [Live preview](http://jsfiddle.net/180ysxLj/)

#### HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button id="btnTaskDone">Task Done</button>
</form>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="task" cols="20" rows="5">...</textarea>    <br />
    <button id="btnSaveTask">Save</button>
</form>
```

#### CSS

```
#btnSaveTask {
    background: orange;
}

#btnTaskDone {
    background: blue;
    display: none; /* This part is the important part */
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#btnSaveTask').click( function(btn) {
   $('#btnTaskDone').show(); 
});
```